# cellcolor don't fill all cell

Tags: tables, cellcolor

I want to fill the cell "physical badging", but when I use `\cellcolor`, a white rectangle appears on the right side.  I don't understand why. The code is below:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline           
&\cellcolor{darkgray!95}\color{white} provider      & \cellcolor{darkgray!95}\color{white} timing & \cellcolor{darkgray!95}\color{white}friction &\cellcolor{darkgray!95}\color{white} resilience & \cellcolor{darkgray!95}\color{white}\makecell{infrastructure\\requirement}\\ \hline
\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{\makecell{manual \\ completion}}   & \makecell{worker or \\ employer} & async  & high & low   & low   \\ \hline
\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{\makecell{physical\\badging}   }& worker    & sync    & mid      & mid to high   & mid to high\\ \hline
\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{digital log}& worker  & sync     & low to mid     & mid    & low to mid \\ \hline
\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{\makecell{geofencing\\-\\smart\\contact\\tracing}}& process & sync & low  & high  & low to mid \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

and the output is:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, you extend your code into a small example that can be compiled please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example works if you specify `p{}` column type with explicit width:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering}p{2.5cm}}
\renewcommand\cellalign{{}{P}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| >{\columncolor{lightgray}}c| *5{c|}}
    \hline
        \rowcolor{darkgray!95}\cellcolor{white}
        & \color{white}provider
        & \color{white}timing
        & \color{white}friction
        & \color{white}resilience
        & \color{white}\makecell{infrastructure\\requirement} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{\makecell{manual\\completion}}
        & \makecell{worker or\\employer}
        & async
        & high
        & low
        & low \\
        \hline
        \textbf{\makecell{physical\\badging}}
        & worker
        & sync
        & mid
        & mid to high
        & mid to high \\
        \hline
        \textbf{\makecell{digital\\log}}
        & worker
        & sync
        & low to mid
        & mid
        & low to mid \\
        \hline
        \textbf{\makecell{geofencing\\-\\smart\\contact\\tracing}}
        & process
        & sync
        & low
        & high
        & low to mid \\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, It's work. Thanks @Celdor.